# 127.0.0.1 corrupted

Tags: windows, network-share, localhost, printer

I can't access my local printers with \\127.0.0.1\printername. Windows XP gives me an error message in my language which roughly translate to :

"Impossible to complete this operation. You have entered a wrong printer name or the specified printer is not connected to the server anymore."

I can't access my pdf printer either through the localhost share.

I **can** access all of them by specifying my computer name instead of 127.0.0.1.

**The source of the problem must be this :** I installed Microsoft Loopback Adapter. Found out it wasn't usefull and uninstall it. Localhost stopped working correctly sometime after that.

My folder shares seems to work out fine but I don't want to take any chances.

Rebooted, Didn't help.

As a demand, here's a (translated as best I can) printout of the "route print" command :

```
===========================================================================
Adapters List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ...... VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
0x3 ...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ...... VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
0x4 ...xx xx xx xx xx xx ...... Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connection
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active routes :
Destination          Mask           Addr. gateway    Adr. adapter   Metric
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      10.1.50.52       20
       10.1.0.0      255.255.0.0       10.1.50.52      10.1.50.52       20
     10.1.50.52  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
 10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.1.50.52      10.1.50.52       20
      127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
   192.168.11.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.11.1    192.168.11.1       20
   192.168.11.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
 192.168.11.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.11.1    192.168.11.1       20
   192.168.64.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.64.1    192.168.64.1       20
   192.168.64.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
 192.168.64.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.64.1    192.168.64.1       20
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       10.1.50.52      10.1.50.52       20
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.11.1    192.168.11.1       20
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.64.1    192.168.64.1       20
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.1.50.52      10.1.50.52       1
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.11.1    192.168.11.1       1
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.64.1    192.168.64.1       1
Default Gateway :          10.1.1.1
===========================================================================
Persistants routes :
  None
```

I have hidden my mac address for security reasons.

Comment: Please go to a command prompt (Start -> Run -> cmd).  Then type "route print" (without quotes) and post the output as an edit to your question.

Comment: Just add it back into your hosts file.

Comment: I tried editing the host file 127.0.0.1 entry. I can write whatever I want there it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried System Restore?

Comment: Do you mean System Restore?

Comment: I didn't try System Restore. Which operation in System Restore do you suggest ?

Comment: Just reset you system state to previous date, when everything worked fine.

Comment: I did other changes since then. So I had another choice, I'd rather try the other one.

Comment: System Restore deactivated. Solves my dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so 10.1.50.52 is, I'm assuming, your "main" physical address with the 192.168. addresses as the VMnet1 & 8. `\\127.0.0.1` doesn't work but `\\machinename` does.

Have you turned off the Server service?

Comment: 10.1.50.52 is my main address. The VMware addresses are used by my virtual machine and should be harmless. Are you asking me to turn off the server service or asking me if it's off ? The server service is started.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to understand what service governs the localhost response on a windows box...it's been a while since I've had to run one. It would be a lot simpler if you just had an Lo0 interface that showed up or down...

Answer (score 1):

1. try to renew your IP with

   ```
   ipconfig /release
   ipconfig /renew
   ```
2. try to delete this route

   ```
   10.1.50.52  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1
   ```

   with

   ```
   route delete 10.1.50.52
   ```

   and add a new one

   ```
   route add 10.1.50.52 mask 255.255.255.255 10.1.50.52
   ```
3. try to flush old DNS information with

   ```
   ipconfig /flushdns
   ```
4. try to enable Loopback adapter back and check
5. check the `hosts` file

Comment: 1 - Renewed ip. Nop. 3 - Tried deleting the route. It can't delete it because it can't find it... stupid MS ? 4 - Flushed the DNS. Nop. 5- Reinstalled MS adapter. Nop. Checked the host file. Same as any host file.

Answer (score 0):

just out of curiosity have you tried  to reinstall the tcp/ip stack on the machine? 
do you have another machine to try ? 
Another thing to point out is this-you are in a 127 address bloc and it's easy to get screwed up there.Move things over if you have to.

Comment: I reinstalled the TCP/IP stack with the following command : netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt. Din't change anything (to my problem).
I don't understand the last part of your answer about the 127 address bloc. However, I'm pretty sure I can't do anything about it since the network is managed my company's technician (who is pretty much clueless about my problem).